# Blinking color shader

Tags: unity, shaders, fragment-shader, cg

Currently i'm using Unity3D, and i want to make one variable blink along time in a fragment shader. Now i have code like this:

```
    half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR{
        float4 r = _OutlineColor;
        r.a = r.a * _SinTime ;
        return r;
        }
```

But this blinking is too slow and not suit me, any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try using a higher frequency sine wave using a multiple of _Time.x or y?